# MMQGIS Error No. 13

Tags: python, geocoding, qgis

I am trying to run a simple geocode call using the `MMQGIS plugin` for `QGIS 2.18`.

I fill the dialog box and make sure the headers selected are the ones I'm interested in, but I keep getting this error message:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\bin/notfound.csv'
```

I've seen `errno13` be a python related issue, but I can't understand how it directly affects the geocoding that I am trying to do here.

If anyone knows what this error means for this plugin, please do let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: According to http://www.davidmckie.com/Geocoding%20Using%20QGIS_New.pdf , it seems `geocoding` isn't any kind of code as referred in programming (though I cannot make sure because I never use the mentioned software). If so, the problem should be put on other professional SE site directly related to GIS.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write the "Not found output list" into a directory where you don't have write permission.

You need to change the path to a writable directory. Something like your Home, or a temp directory.

Regards